# ReactJs State changes but re-rendering requires a click on button

Tags: reactjs

I have nested components where in child component a function from upper components gets called and state changes in that component. State is passed to child using props. The problem is when state changes, the content wont change unless i click on it. Here my component is a Button.

```
render(

    <React.Fragment>

        <Button className="h-64 remove-user-tab" onClick={userMenuClick}>
            <Avatar className="" alt="user photo" src={props.userInfo.data.avatar}/>

            <div className="hidden md:flex flex-col mx-12 items-start">
                <Typography component="span" className="normal-case font-600 flex">
                    {props.userInfo.data.first_name + ' ' + props.userInfo.data.last_name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography className="text-11 capitalize" color="textSecondary">
                    {props.userInfo.role.toString()}
                </Typography>
            </div>

            <Icon className="text-16 hidden sm:flex" variant="action">keyboard_arrow_down</Icon>
        </Button>

    </React.Fragment>

)
```

`updateUserInfo()` and `userInfo` is passed from main component to children using props. I call `props.updateUserInfo()` function inside another child which updates `userInfo` state in parent child. Then i expect sibling child to re-render its content but re-rendering the above piece of code requires a click on that button to take effect. How can i solve it?

Comment: could you share `updateUserInfo` implementation?

Comment: ```updateUserInfo(info) { this.setState({ userInfo: info }); }``` @buzatto

Comment: That looks OK. other point of attention would be how Child creates  the next user Info and calls `updateUserInfo`. If you could share it could reveal the core problem